# Big O complexity for counting occurences in list using dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, big-o

I have list of numbers `nums = [1,1,2,3,3]` and want to create a dict containing number of occurences of those numbers `{1:2,2:1,3:2}`

If I do it using dict comprehension like this: `cntDict = {n:nums.count(n) for n in set(nums)}` is it slower than looping through array and increasing the counts one by one?

Comment: Yes, because each `n` will trigger a separate pass through `nums` to count each number.

Comment: This doesn’t answer your actual question, but depending on what your goals are, you may want to check out [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nums.count()` is O(n) and you invoke it (at worst) O(n) times, so the resulting complexity is O(n²).

Going through the array and bumping a frequency count is only O(n).

Comment: Big-O can be misleading sometimes, because this only describes the time complexity for part of the operation. Each set operation is still gonna be O(log(n)). Note that if the array was already sorted to begin with, a second array containing counts can be built in O(n) time while also condensing the original array. A straight report of counts is then also linear while preserving O(log(n)) search, similar to a set but with better memory/cache efficiency.